# Null Context Issue

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have `getdata` class and one more class `Checks`. `getdata` is passing `context` to `Checks` to call their internet connection check method. But here i'm getting an error for nullpoint exception.To check whether `mcontext` is null or not I am fetching device id and getting value also.

Code for `getdata` class:

```
public class getdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context mcontext;
    private String message;


    getdata(Context context, String msg) {
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.message = msg;
    }

    Checks checks = new Checks(mcontext);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) throws IllegalStateException {
        System.out.println("Starting");

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        System.out.println(id);
        try {
            if (checks.checkinternet()) {
Log.i("Internet Status","Found");
}
}
```

Code for `Checks` class:

```
public class Checks {

    private Context mContext;

    public Checks(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }



    boolean checkinternet() {


        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeinternet = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeinternet != null && activeinternet.isConnected();

    }}
```

Now through NPE at during checking internet status? Not getting clue where I did mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your Checks before assigning `this.mcontext = context;` inside your constructor.

So modify your code like below and initialize Checks inside your constructor :-

```
public class getdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context mcontext;
    private String message;

    Checks checks = null;
    getdata(Context context, String msg) {
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.message = msg;
        checks = new Checks(mcontext);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) throws IllegalStateException {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)   mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        System.out.println(id);
        try {
            if (checks.checkinternet()) {
                Log.i("Internet Status","Found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but a query, like I created object below constructor with view that context has got value to pass now, but it is not. why so.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: getdata(Context context, String msg) {
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.message = msg;
    }

    Checks checks = new Checks(mcontext);
 I called after assigning right? As this.mcontext is in line 2.

Comment: I think you forgot the constructor parenthesis. Your earlier call for Check was done before context variable was assigned inside constructor.